# Redirect old links example.com/oscthumb.php?src=/images/3-A_in.jpg&w=960&h=647&f=jpg&q=95&hash=6b

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, phpthumb

I have indexed several images that I need to redirect using .htaccess

The old urls are like:

```
example.com/oscthumb.php?src=/images/3-A_in.jpg&w=960&h=647&f=jpg&q=95&hash=6b884jduhh3h8737h
```

and they have to become:

```
example.com/images/3-A_in.jpg
```

Images can have any image extensions and any file name. This part

```
oscthumb.php?src=/images/
```

is always the same.

I tried several options using .htaccess online testers but I'm unable to make it work.

Comment: Does the new URL work if you direct access it?

Comment: @starkeen yes the image is there so it will be rendered without problem

Comment: @starkeen can you help me? thanks

Answer (score 0):

To redirect the old URLs to new ones , you can use the following rule in your `.htaccess` file :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond ℅{THE_REQUEST} /oscthumb\.php\?src=/images/([^\s]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^.+$ http://example.com/images/%1? [L,R]
```

Change `R` to `R=301` to make the redirection permanent when you are sure the rule is working ok.

Comment: Thank you. I've tried it but it doesn't redirect, returns a 404 error. It is a Prestashop installation, do you know the reason?